# Изометрическая сетка (Grid) для портфолио

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-дизайн

Хочу сделать такой же эффект: 
https://tympanus.net/Development/IsometricGrids/index.html

Полагаю, по любому существуют такие JS скрипты. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Довольно просто, CSS3 позволяет делать неплохие штуки в плане 3D, например: https://habrahabr.ru/post/151300/

Comment: тут можно и с css обойтись